# Tiles 3: get current definition name inside a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, tiles

Is there a method to retrieve the name of the current called definition inside a jsp?

the tag

```
<tiles:importAttribute>
```

only works with attributes of a definition

Comment: You can always add another attribute to definition and use it. Also see http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/Access-definition-name-other-proeprties-from-jsp-context-td3554644.html.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** In `tiles.xml` add attribute `myDefinitionName` in all definitions.

```
<definition name="baseLayout" template="/BaseLayout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="" type="string"  />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/Header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/Menu.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/Footer.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="myDefinitionName" cascade="true" value="baseLayout"  />
</definition>

<definition name="/welcome.tiles" extends="baseLayout">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome" type="string" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/welcome.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="myDefinitionName" cascade="true" value="welcome.tiles"  />
</definition>
```

**Note:** Use proper tiles version and `tiles.xml dtd` to use `cascade="true"`.

**Step 2:** In `welcome.jsp`

```
<b>Definition Name :</b> <tiles:getAsString name="myDefinitionName"/>
```

**Output:**

> **Definition Name :** welcome.tiles